# Strip characters from ng-repeat filter?

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing an Angular app that will read a magnetic stripe card from a USB device. When I swipe a test card, I get a string back containing the card number. For example, `;12345?`, where `12345` is the card number.

The data my app uses doesn't include these "control characters", so I'd like to strip them out of the search string if the string starts with a `;` and ends with a `?`.

When I write a custom filter:

```
angular.module('app.filters', [])

.filter('stripcardcontrolcharacters', function() {
  return function(text) {
    if(text.substring(0, 1) === ";" && text.substring(text.length - 1) === "?") {
        return text.substring(1, text.length - 1);
    }
  };
});
```

It fails because I'm `ng-repeat`ing over an array, and not the string that I've searched for.

How would I get what string I'm filtering for and strip the characters from it?

EDIT: Current suggestion is to use a filter to modify the array to ADD in the control characters so `filter:` can find it. I might go with that for now, but I'm still *curious to know if you can write such a filter*

Comment: 1) Your filter doesn't do anything. 2) How are you intending to use it?

Comment: Yeah for testing purposes I just wanted to output the string. In the actual filter, I'd test for ; and ? as the first & last characters. Right now I'm trying to use it like so: `<tr ng-repeat="user in users | stripcardcontrolcharacters | filter:query">` and my input tag looks like this: `<input ng-model="query.$" id="searchinput" name="searchinput" type="search" placeholder="Name, Card Number etc.">`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the entire array to your filter via

```
ng-repeat="user in users | stripcardcontrolcharacters ...
```

If that's how you want it to work, you would need to treat it as an array, for example

```
return function(textArray) {
    var invalidChars = /\D/g; // just an example
    return textArray.map(text => {
        console.log(text);
        return text.replace(invalidChars, '');
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I might have to modify the array directly to ADD in the control characters so `filter:` can find them. Was hoping to strip the characters from the string so it could quickly and robustly handle data for any query.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably applying the filter to the array, not the string itself.
Look at this example:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('testController', function($scope){
    $scope.names = ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'];
  })
  // The test filter
  .filter('strip', function(){
    return function(str) {
      return str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
    };
  });
```

And here is how to use it:

```
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="testController">
    <p ng-repeat="name in names">
        {{name | strip }}
    </p>
</body>
```

Note that I'm applying the filter where I use the value, not in the `ng-repeat` statement.

[And here is the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VYXZKv)

Comment: Because I intend to use the value to filter an array, instead of just displaying an array, this wouldn't work for me. But it has opened my eyes as to how filters work, so thank you for that :)